# Is there a name/notation for coordinate-wise identical function?

Tags: functions, terminology

Let's define $g: \mathbb{U}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{V}^n$ where $\mathbb{U}$ and $\mathbb{V}$ are arbitrary sets as

$$g(u) = \left[f(u_1), f(u_2), \ldots, f(u_n) \right]^T$$

for some $f: \mathbb{U} \rightarrow \mathbb{V}$. In other words, $g$ applies the same scalar function $f$ to each coordinate of the input.

Do such functions have a special name? Is there a special name for similar functions where there are $n$ scalar functions $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n$ that are all applied coordinate-wise to construct a single function?

Comment: Surely computer science has a name for such constructions, anyway.

Comment: @Travis Good point. I'll move the question there if I don't get reasonable answers here. Also, perhaps other tags could be more appropriate?

Comment: I would call it a diagonal map, but I'm not sure if that terminology is standard for sets.  It is used to linear spaces.

Comment: @Phonon I've replaced the analysis tag with the terminology tag.